# "dpkg-source: unrepresentable changes to source" when trying to debuild a modified package

Tags: debuild

I downloaded the source to a package using:

```
$ apt-get source gkrellweather
```

I also made sure I had the compile dependencies:

```
$ sudo apt-get build-dep gkrellweather
```

And I tested that it could build fine:

```
$ cd gkrellweather-2.0.8
$ debuild
```

It built a `.deb` package in the folder above, which I could install using:

```
$ sudo dpkg -i ../gkrellweather*.deb
```

OK so everything is in place.  Let's get started!

I opened up the source code in Vim and made some changes I wanted.  Then I tried to rebuild:

```
$ debuild
```

But I got the following error:

```
...
dh_clean: Compatibility levels before 5 are deprecated (level 4 in use)
 dpkg-source -b gkrellweather-2.0.8
dpkg-source: warning: no source format specified in debian/source/format, see dpkg-source(1)
dpkg-source: info: using source format `1.0'
dpkg-source: info: building gkrellweather using existing gkrellweather_2.0.8.orig.tar.gz
dpkg-source: info: building gkrellweather in gkrellweather_2.0.8-2.diff.gz
dpkg-source: error: cannot represent change to gkrellweather-2.0.8/.gkrellweather.c.swp: binary file contents changed
dpkg-source: warning: the diff modifies the following upstream files: 
 GrabWeather
 Makefile
 gkrellweather.c
dpkg-source: info: use the '3.0 (quilt)' format to have separate and documented changes to upstream files, see dpkg-source(1)
dpkg-source: unrepresentable changes to source
dpkg-buildpackage: error: dpkg-source -b gkrellweather-2.0.8 gave error exit status 1
debuild: fatal error at line 1357:
dpkg-buildpackage -rfakeroot -D -us -uc failed
```

Why?

Answer (score 7):

Thanks to joeytwiddle's answer as it gave me a great place to start in my solution to this issue.

In my Python project that I attempted to create a debian package for, I am using:

- pybuild to prepare the debian package before running debuild
- git for version control
- PyCharm IDE for the Python development

*git creates a `.git` directory, pybuild creates a `.pybuild` directory and PyCharm creates a `.idea` directory all in the root of my project.*

Because joeytwiddle mentioned that debuild didn't like a certain file (in his case a swp file) then I felt it probably had a fit about the hidden directories. I found out that for git, you can do: `debuild -i` and it ignores version control directories for as for the pybuild and idea directories, I have not found another option yet. **So for my solution, I copied over my project to a blank directory, deleted `.git`, `.idea`, and `.pybuild` directories** and success!

Comment: `-i` gets passed through `debuild` to `dpkg-buildpackage` and then to `dpkg-source`, whose man page says that a regexp can be provided. Without testing, I guess `-i'(^|/)\.(git|idea|pybuild)($|/)'` might work for you.

Answer (score 3):

This has tripped me up more than once before.  Sometimes I thought the reason for debuild errors after changing the source was that after the source has been changed, the package maintainers signature (signoff) is no longer valid for that source.

But actually in this case the answer was simple:

```
dpkg-source: error: cannot represent change to gkrellweather-2.0.8/.gkrellweather.c.swp: binary file contents changed
```

The problem is that **Vim had created a swafile**, and `debuild` didn't like that!

The solution was simple: remove the swapfile, and then building can work:

```
$ rm ./.gkrellweather.c.swp
$ debuild
```