# ubuntu build kernel from git with a source change, how to ignore 'unrepresentable changes to source' error

Tags: kernel, deb, git

I have modified a source file in the i915 source code. 
I have just edited the file and made a change to one line.

I have not made a patch file because I couldn't work out how to do that. 
 When I build with

```
make -j `getconf _NPROCESSORS_ONLN` deb-pkg LOCALVERSION=-custom
```

or with

```
make -j `getconf _NPROCESSORS_ONLN` deb-pkg LOCALVERSION=-custom -i
```

I get

```
 update-version-dkms
dpkg-source: info: use the '3.0 (quilt)' format to have separate and documented changes to upstream files, see dpkg-source(1)
dpkg-source: error: unrepresentable changes to source
dpkg-buildpackage: error: dpkg-source -i.git -b ubuntu-bionic subprocess returned exit status 1
scripts/package/Makefile:71: recipe for target 'deb-pkg' failed
make[1]: [deb-pkg] Error 1 (ignored)
```

Then I committed that change tp a new branch and checked out a standard tag (a standard upstream version). Previously it built. Now it doesn't, same error.

the answer here hints at some bad files (example vim swap files) but I can't work out what the problems may be: ["dpkg-source: unrepresentable changes to source" when trying to debuild a modified package](https://askubuntu.com/questions/434695/dpkg-source-unrepresentable-changes-to-source-when-trying-to-debuild-a-modifi) 
does not help me.

Comment: ya, `deb-pkg` got broken quite awhile ago now. Substitute `bindeb-pkg`. I am not certain for your case though. I always use, for example, and just a few minutes ago: `time make -j9 olddefconfig bindeb-pkg LOCALVERSION=-doug4` (I always time the compile). Oh, I see you answered yourself.

Answer (score 2):

Ah, my local changes were a red-herring.
somehow a python script got added in part of the source tree, some kind of debugging assistant.

To fix:
1 Following instructions here to remove all non-tracked files from the working tree

https://koukia.ca/how-to-remove-local-untracked-files-from-the-current-git-branch-
571c6ce9b6b1

I did

```
To remove ignored and non-ignored files, run git clean -f -x or git clean -fx
```

2. Return to the instructions here: 
   https://wiki.ubuntu.com/KernelTeam/GitKernelBuild

at step 4, copy the config in.

Then it builds.

these are my complete notes. Some of these steps are unnecessary but they don't hurt. Obviously, ignore the cherry-pick.

```
fakeroot debian/rules clean
cp /boot/config-`uname -r` .config
yes '' | make oldconfig
make clean
#remove the non git files
git clean -f
rm vmlinux-gdb.py
#make sure there is no linux*.tar too
rm ../linux*.gz

#cherry pick RC6 hack
git cherry-pick 0c6b6fa52c6ad54332eed64acb6aebc59f75e0b2

#
make -j `getconf _NPROCESSORS_ONLN` deb-pkg LOCALVERSION=-custom
cd ..
```